# Заполнить список в ходе итераций

Tags: python, list, for

Нужно заполнить список в ходе итераций. Допустим цикл

```
for x in range(6):
    a = x+1
```

прибавляет к `x` `1`, хотелось бы чтобы результат`a`записался в список как-то так: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. 
Где хотелось бы переменить

```
cache = [[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)],
 [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, -1)],
 [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (-2, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)],
 [(0, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, -1)],
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 1)],
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
 [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1)],
 [(0, 0), (0, -1), (-1, -1)],
 [(0, 0), (0, -1), (0, 0)],
 [(0, 0), (0, -1), (0, -2)]]
# Compute the average end-to-end distance of random walks of a given lengt
for x in range (len(cache)):
    iks = (j for i in map(lambda x: tuple(zip(*x))[0], cache) for j in i)
    y = (j for i in map(lambda x: tuple(zip(*x))[1], cache) for j in i)
    iks1 = list(iks)
    y1 = list(y)
    f = lambda iks1, n=3: [iks1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(iks1), n)]
    f = lambda y1, n=3: [y1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(y1), n)]
    iks_elem=f(iks1)
    y_elem = f(y1)
for f in range(len(iks_elem)):
    iks_max = max(iks_elem[f])
    y_max = max(y_elem[f])
    x1=0
    y1 = 0    
    r = lambda iks_max,y_max, y1, x1: [sqrt((iks_max-x1)**2 + (y_max-y1)**2)]
    ab = r(iks_max,y_max, y1, x1)
    print (ab)
```

Comment: `var = [i + 1 for i in range(6)]` или смотрите методы списка в частности `append`.

Comment: Наверно не не совсем правильный пример привела, в той задаче где хотелось бы использовать заполнение списка в ходе итераций возвращаются циклом значения функции в виде `float` чисел. Отредактировала вопрос и вставила код, к которому это хотелось бы применить.

Comment: У вас один задачник? Схожий вопрос был с утра.

Comment: Да, пока один. Постараюсь больше не дублировать схожие по тематике вопросы. В любом случае ваш ответ и ответ выше помог полностью разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**for loop**

```
new_list = []
for i in range(10):
    new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**list Comprehensions**

```
new_list = [i for i in range(10)]
print(new_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**map() list**

```
items = list(range(10)) 
squared = list(map(lambda x: x**2, items))
print(squared)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

**list() list**

```
new_list = list(range(10))
print(new_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```